# Javascript fetch api use custom error message

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm looking for a way of handling errors with the native javascript fetch api. Used to use jQuery, but I'm trying to use more native javascript functions.

I found this blog and like the approach: https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-handle-fetch-errors/

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status <= 299) {
      return response.json();
    } 

    throw Error(response.statusText);
    
  })
  .then((jsonResponse) => {
    // do whatever you want with the JSON response
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle the error
    console.log(error);
  });
```

However, in the catch I'm getting the statusText that belongs to the HTTP code. For 400 for example `Bad request`. But that is not wat I want, my call to the server will respond with exactly what is wrong. So I want to use the response body text as a the error. I tried different ways, but I can't get the response body incase the HTTP code is 400. With jQuery I used `response.responseJSON.html`. But this is not available with the fetch api.

So how can I can use the response body as error code.

Comment: What does response.statusText return?

Comment: In case of `400`, `Bad request`. If 401 `Unauthorized`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

Comment: I thought that it was the message from the server. So could you look for your message in the response's body. It should be there and you could use throw Error(response.message).

Comment: No, if I `console.log(response)` I can't find my response body.

Comment: @Timo002 What if you try `response.text().then(console.log);` - does that display the correct error message?

Comment: @RichardDeeming, then I will get a `[object Promise]` error on the console.

Comment: How about with `(async ()=> { const text = await response.text(); console.log(text); })();`? If you still get an error, what's the full error message?

Comment: @RichardDeeming, that will put the resonse body in the `text` variable. Now I need to put it all together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[The `fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) was designed to work best with [`async` functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function). If you can make your outer function `async`, your code would become:

```javascript
try {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  if (!response.ok) {
    const text = await response.text();
    throw Error(text);
  }
  
  const jsonResponse = await response.json();
  // do whatever you want with the JSON response
    
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

Otherwise, it gets a bit more complicated:

```
fetch(url)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.ok) {
      return response.json();
    }
    
    return response.text().then((text) => throw Error(text));
  })
  .then((jsonResponse) => {
    // do whatever you want with the JSON response
  }).catch((error) => {
    // Handle the error
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: This is great! Best answer online :) I've been looking for a way to show my JSON error message that came back from ```Node.js``` so I still to had to do response.json(); no matter what! ```async await``` solves it perfectly.